# IPhone FBConnect post to page wall

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I need help in topic.

I use GraphAPI. 
I can post to my own wall with using:

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];`

I can post image to group wall using:

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[group_id_here]/photos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];`

But when I try:

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[page_id_here]/photos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];`

I have no luck. What's wrong?
Thanks in advance